# Where does Eleven's mind go when she is in the sensory-deprivation tank?

Tags: plot-explanation, stranger-things

Where does Eleven's mind go when she is in the sensory-deprivation tank in *Stranger Things*? Is it an alternate reality? Or is it a parallel universe? Did she travel time or space?

Comment: It's called the "upside down". It's pretty mush a parallel universe.

Comment: Its called astral projection.  The Americans and the Russians did experiments during the cold war, the idea of astral projection being one such experiment.  Eleven is that experiment in this show.  This is all explained in the show.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is called [isolation tank](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolation_tank) or sensory-deprivation tank:

> An isolation tank is a lightless, soundproof tank inside which subjects float in salt water at skin temperature.

That said, you can see that she is able to project her mind near a target in a different geographic area and listen to them talking (when Dr Brenner uses that to eavesdrop the Russians).

From [IMDB](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt4574334/synopsis):

> Using a sensory-deprivation tank and hooked to the wave machine, they use her to collect information from a Russian man...

and

> She then flashes-back to finding the Russian, where she "casts Shadowwalk" - projects herself on the astral plane to locate people - on him, but finds the monster and it gives chase

Doesn't look like she can time travel - at least not in the first season.

Comment: I agree to your answer; But in episode 6, it is told that the "Eleven" has abilities like telepathy and telekinesis. So, is it sign she might be time traveling sooner in upcoming season?

Comment: It's not a sign of anything until the writers write that she can do so. Telekinesis and telepathy are not necessarily related to time travel.

Comment: Although in the mythology of [remote viewing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_viewing) there is the idea that it covers psychic travel in both time and space.

Answer (score 4):

It's known as [remote viewing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_viewing) in conspiracy circles.

The show draws on the real and mythical history of the [MKUltra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Project_MKUltra) experiments.